# Adding markers to Google Map generated in Ajax request response

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a Google Map that I would like to add markers denoting the location of membership addresses, but I have a slight problem that I don't quite understand.

If I have the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                              zoom: 8
                            });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: {lat: 39.099, lng: -105.129},
                          map: map,
                          title: ''
                        });
```

The above successfully creates the map and adds the marker successfully, so I know I'm on the right track. But when I go to edit the script into the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                              zoom: 8
                            });

                        $.each(data[1].locations, function(i, item) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: {lat: item.latitude, lng: item.longitude},
                          map: map,
                          title: ''
                        });
                        });
```

This time, the map is created but no markers are shown (even though the above does correctly response to appropriate coordinates, I get the following error in my console: `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Comment: console.log the item, the property name for latitude and longitude may be diffferent

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that markers are being added only after ajax request is completed.
Add marker only in ajax's success part.

Example :

```
$.ajax({
    url:    "ajaxmap.php",
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {

  $.each(data[1].locations, function(i, item) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: {lat: item.latitude, lng: item.longitude},
                          map: map,
                          title: ''
                        });

}
```